# I am trying to change the Mesh texture of a tool in a players backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a part and added a script with a function that detects if the part was touched. If a player touches this part I need to access that players Backpack and a find a tool. In this case, it is a Pistol. I then try to change the `TextureId` of the Pistols mesh, which is inside of the Handle part within the Pistol

I have tried accessing the players backpack by using `hit.Parent.Backpack`,
but when I touch the part I get an error in the console saying

> Backpack is not a valid member of Accessory

Here is the entire script...

```lua
function onTouched(hit)
    local player = hit.Parent
    local p = player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Pistol")
    local h = p:FindFirstChild("Handle")
    local m = h:FindFirstChild("Mesh")
    local id = m.TextureId

    id = "rbxassetid://3707943717"
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(onTouched)
```

The expected result should be:

When a player touches this part it should look for a "Pistol" in the players Backpack and then look for the pistols "Mesh" and change the meshes "TextureId" to whatever texture I have set it to in the script.

Comment: My best guess is that `hit.Parent` isn't actually the player but something else.

Comment: Now i think hit.Parent is just the model. If that is true i cant really think of any way to access the Backpack like this. But i feel like i should do more research now so i don't waste anyone's time. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this after some more research. My first mistake is that hit.Parent seems to only be the model. So i used that to find the "Humanoid" then from there got the name of the player so that i can find the player in the player list and access the backpack to change the pistols "Mesh.TextureId"

Here is the new script...

```
function onTouched(m)
    local p = m.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

    if p ~= nil then
        local n = p.Parent.Name
        local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(n, false) -- find the player that hit the Part.
        local gun = player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Pistol")

        if player == nil then return end -- escape if something goes wrong.

        local handle = gun:FindFirstChild("Handle")
        local mesh = handle.Mesh

        mesh.TextureId = "rbxassetid://3707943717" -- change the gun texture
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(onTouched)
```